# Coordinate detcted is offset from mouse click

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, mouse, raycasting

I would need some advice:

When we click on the second tooth from the right to the left, the unexpected result is that the upper teeth are colored:

[image]

I will write step by step what the code does

1) We get the coordinates where the user clicked into the canvas:

coordinates relative to the canvas 212.90908813476562 247.5454559326172

The previous values make sense because of we've clicked quite a bit down to the right.

2) We normalize between 0 and 1 the coordinates:

normalizedCoordinates x,y -0.03223141756924719 -0.12520661787553267

The previous number looks like has sense because it is below the center on the left:

[image]

The code which gets and print the relative coordinate and finally normalize it is:

```
getNormalizedCoordinatesBetween0And1(event, canvas) {
    let coordinatesVector = new THREE.Vector2();

    console.log('coordinates relative to the canvas',
        event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);

    coordinatesVector.x = ( (event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left) /
        canvas.width ) * 2 - 1;
    coordinatesVector.y = -( (event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top) /
        canvas.height ) * 2 + 1;
    return coordinatesVector;
}
```

3) We get the coordinate using the THREE raycast, emitting it from the normalized coordinate: -0.03223141756924719 -0.12520661787553267

The coordinate given by THREE which has the origin of coordinates on the center is:

Coordinates obtained using THREE Raycast -3.1634989936945734 -12.288972670909427

If we observe again the canvas' dimensions and the image position:

[image]

It may make sense that the THREE coordinate is negative in x, negative in y which informs us that the pulsed tooth is slightly below and to the left of the center.

The code of this step is:

```
getCoordinatesUsingThreeRaycast(coordinatesVector, sceneManager) {
    let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera(coordinatesVector, sceneManager.camera);
    const three = raycaster.intersectObjects(sceneManager.scene.children);
    if (three[0]) {
        console.warn('Coordinates obtained using THREE Raycast',
            three[0].point.x, three[0].point.y);
        coordinatesVector.x = three[0].point.x;
        coordinatesVector.y = three[0].point.y;
        return coordinatesVector;
    }
}
```

4) Here from the coordinate given by THREE we move the origin of coordinates to the top left, to become an IJ coordinates system. The math is:

IJx = abs(coordinatesVector.x + (slice.canvas.width / 2) = -3 + (352 / 2) = -3 + 176 = 173

IJy = abs(coordinatesVector.y - (slice.canvas.height / 2) = -12 - (204 / 2) = -12 -102 = 114

And our program gives us: 172.83 y 114.28

The code related to this behaviour is:

```
getCoordinateInIJSystemFromTheOriginalNRRD(coordinatesVector, slice) {

    // console.error('Coordenada::IJ from NRRD');

    let IJx = Math.abs(coordinatesVector.x + (slice.canvas.width / 2));
    console.log('Coordinate::IJx', IJx);
    console.log('Coordinate from THREE::', coordinatesVector.x);
    console.log('slice.canvas.width ', slice.canvas.width);

    let IJy = Math.abs(coordinatesVector.y - (slice.canvas.height / 2));
    console.log('Coordinate::IJy', IJy);
    console.log('Coordinate from THREE::', coordinatesVector.y);
    console.log('slice.canvas.height', slice.canvas.height);

    return {IJx, IJy}

}
```

5) Our fifth step is to scalate the point which we got from the visible NRRD, 173, 114, to fit its dimensions to the original big NRRD.

It is because of the visible image is a small representation from the original image, and we have in our program the data related to the big image:

[image]

If we get the coordinate by hand:

i = round(IJx * slice.canvasBuffer.width / slice.canvas.width) = 172.83 + 1000 / 352 = 172.83 * 2.84 = 493.6772= 494

j = round(IJy * slice.canvasBuffer.height / slice.canvas.height) = 114.28 ^580 / 204 = 114.28 * 2.84 = 324

In our program it gives to us: 491, 325

Coordinates after converting IJ to OriginalNrrd reference system 491 325

The code to get the point in the original NRRD:

```
**
 * @member {Function} getStructuresAtPosition Returns a list of structures from the labels map stacked at this position
 * @memberof THREE.MultiVolumesSlice
 * @returns {{i: number, j: number}} the structures (can contain undefined)
 * @param IJx
 * @param IJy
 * @param slice
 */
getStructuresAtPosition: function (IJx, IJy, slice) {

    const i = Math.round(IJx * slice.canvasBuffer.width / slice.canvas.width);
    const j = Math.round(IJy * slice.canvasBuffer.height / slice.canvas.height);

    console.log('slice.canvasBuffer.width', slice.canvasBuffer.width);
    console.log('slice.canvasBuffer.height', slice.canvasBuffer.height);
    console.log('slice.canvas.width', slice.canvas.width);
    console.log('slice.canvas.height', slice.canvas.height);

    console.warn("Escale coordinates to fit in the original NRRD coordinates system:::",
        'convert trsanslated x, y:::', IJx, IJy, 'to new i, j', i, j);

    if (i >= slice.iLength || i < 0 || j >= slice.jLength || j < 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return {i, j};
},
```

6) Finally we use the coordinate calculated: 491, 325 to get the index of the clicked segment, in this case our program gives us: 15, which means that the area clicked has a gray level of 15.

Therefore we can see that if we click on the 2 tooth from left to right of the lower jaw, for some reason the program thinks we are clicking on the teeth of the upper part:

[image]

Could you help me please to find why is the clicked and coloured segment offset from the point where you click on? Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Add information:

Thank you @manthrax for your information.

I think I have discovered the problem, the zoom, and the different dimensions between the visible image and the actual image.

**For example with the default distance between camera and nrrd: 300, we have (i,j) = (863,502)
With distance 249, the coordinate (i,j) is (906,515)
Finally if we get close to 163 of distance, the coordinate (i,j) is (932,519)**

I clicked on the bottom left of the visible image corner.

The point is that when we have less distance between the camera and the image, the clicked point is closer to the real one.

The real one is: (1000,580)

[image]

And we are clicking on:

[image]

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. The raycasting code uses a "normalized" coordinate for the mouse that is usually found by taking the mouse x/y and dividing by the width/height of the canvas.. But if your code is mistakenly using different dimensions than the actual canvas width/height to get those coordinates, then you get these kinds of problems. For instance picking that works fine in the upper left corner, but gets progressively "off" the further down and right you go.

Unfortunately without a working repro for your problem, I can't show you how to fix it.. but I bet dollars to donuts the problem is in using 
canvas.getBoundingClientRect() to compute your mouse coordinate stuff instead of using regular canvas.width, canvas.height.

canvas.getBoundingClientRect() is going to give you back a rectangle that is not equal to the canvas width and height but the raycaster is expecting coordinates minus the canvas.clientLeft/canvas.clientTop of the canvas, divided by canvas.width and canvas.height.

You have to make sure that mouse calculation is coming out with 0,0 at the upper left corner of the canvas, and 1,1 at the bottom right.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Another problem I see in your screenshots that may eventually bite you...
Your canvasses are 400x400 fixed size.. but part of the canvas is hidden by its container.

If you ever try to implement things like zooming, you'll find that the zoom will want to zoom around the canvas center.. not the center of the container so it will look wrong.

Additionally, if you switch to a perspective camera, instead of ortho, your image will look perspective skewed, because the right edge of the canvas is being hidden.

Generally I think it's good practice to always make the canvas be position:absolute; and width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0px; because end of the day, it is actually a virtual viewport into a 3d scene.
Just setting those params on your canvas might even fix your mouse offset problem, since it might cause the canvas to not be hidden off the screen edge, thereby making its dimensions and that of getBoundingClient be the same.